# Defining an "additive" group structure on $[0,1]$

Tags: group-theory, binary-operations

Addition modulo $1$ defines a group structure on the halfopen unit interval $[0,1)$. Obviously, this construction does not work if one starts with $[0,1]$ instead of $[0,1)$.

Is it possible to extend addition on $[0,1]$ to a group operation? More precisely:

> Does there exist a binary operation $\ast: [0,1]^2 \to [0,1]$ such
>   that $a \ast b = a+b$ whenever $a+b \leq 1$ and such that
>   $([0,1],\ast)$ is a group?

Clearly, if this is the case then $0$ should be the neutral element. However, we did not make much progress beyond this. This question came up when trying to invent exercises for a group theory course. I do not know what the answer is.

Comment: Did you want the resulting group to be a topological group?  I.e., did you want to come up with a binary operation that is continuous?

Comment: $[0, 1]$ cannot be made a topological group in any way (so $\ast$ cannot be continuous); the reason is that it is not homogeneous (there are no homeomorphisms exchanging either of the boundary points with any point in the interior).

Comment: But what if $\ast$ is not continuous?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan is that to do with cut points? Also $\ast: I\times I \to I$, how does it apply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such operation, continuous or not. Observe that if $a,b\in [0,1]$ are such that $a+b>1$, then
$$
a*b = 1*(a+b-1) .\quad\quad\quad\quad (1)
$$

To see this, just write 
$$
b=(1-a)+(a+b-1)=(1-a)*(a+b-1) ;
$$
this gives (1) after multiplication by $a$.

Now fix $a$ and consider $a*x$, $0\le x\le 1$. This defines a bijection on $[0,1]$, and since $0\le x\le 1-a$ gets mapped bijectively onto $[a,1]$, it follows that $x\mapsto 1*(a+x-1)$ must map $(1-a,1]$ bijectively onto $[0,a)$.

Equivalently, $y\mapsto 1*y$ must map $(0,a]$ bijectively onto $[0,a)$, but this isn't working because now the $y$ with $1*y=0$ would have to be in $(0,a]$ for all $a>0$.

Comment: Should (1) read $a \ast b = c(a,b) \ast (a+b)$?

Comment: @user133281: I meant what I wrote, but since $1^c=c$ for $c=0,1$ (since $x^0$ is defined to be the identity in a group, which is $0$ here), this happens to be the same thing.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: The above comments refer to an earlier version of this answer; I've now cleaned up the notation a little.