# Determining whether a binary operation is a group.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $X = [0, 1]$. We look at the binary function $\ast$ defined by:

$  x \ast y = x + y$, if $x+y \leq 1$

$ x \ast y = x + y - 1$, otherwise

Determine if $(X, \ast)$ is a group.

I've looked at all three aspects of what constitutes a group: associativity, identity and the presence of an inverse. Now, I'm fairly sure that $(X, \ast)$ is associative and has an identity (the identity being $0$), but I'm unsure if it has an inverse or not. I'm not experienced in group theory, but I think that the only inverse element of an element $x$ in $X$ can be $-x$, which is not an element of $X$ itself if $x =1$. Is this the correct way of thinking about this problem?

Comment: No. Perhaps you should take some example for $x\in\left[0,1\right]$, and try to find their inverses, if exist. For example, what are the inverses of $\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}$?

Comment: If $0$ is indeed the identity, then you need $x*x^{-1}=0$. If $x+x^{-1}\le 1$, then $x*x^{-1}=x+x^{-1}$ which is nonzero if $x\neq 0$. If $x+x^{-1}>1$, then $x*x^{-1}=x+x^{-1}-1>0$.

Comment: $1$ is also almost like an identity: $1*x=x$ whenever $x\neq0$. This leads to a problem not unlike the one where you show that the identity element is unique. We cannot remedy the situation by using $1$ as the identity, because $0\in X$ and $0*1\neq0$. Throw out $0$ and you have a group with $1$ as the identity (and its own inverse), and $1-x$ as the inverse of $x<1$.

Comment: This http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924170/ is a more general result.